# Error while tried to install "kivy" library

Tags: python, kivy

Pip version -- 23.1.2
Python version -- 3.11.2

Error :

(kivy_venv) PS C:\Users\name> pip install kivy==2.1.0

```
    `Collecting kivy==2.1.0
  Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-67.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
      Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
      Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
        Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1, 0.6.0)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.`
```

I tried to install it with pipwin, but got another error

(kivy_venv) PS C:\Users\user> pipwin install kivy==2.1.0

```
Package `kivy` not found
Try `pipwin refresh`
```

(pipwin refresh not working)

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html) `Kivy 2.1.0 officially supports Python versions 3.7 - 3.10.`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue. I resolved it by downloading "Terminal" in my app store (for windows). Instead of just running my terminal, I make sure to run as admin, this is helpful to avoid --user error when trying to pip install. Afterwards I just followed the provided [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-pip).